# Changing the window in an exterior door

Tags: windows, doors

We were given a new fibreglass door but it is RH instead of LH.  How do we change the window so it will be facing the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by a window?  WHat would changing the window have to do with the incorrect door?  Please provide more details.

Comment: Maybe a picture would help.

Comment: Might want to also check with the manufacturer -- some can be really *REALLY* picky on servicing and you don't want to prematurely void any warranties.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you are after... Is what you are saying is that the out side of the door is now on the inside and vice-versa?  Many Fiberglass doors do look the same on both sides and have decoritive windows that look different from the inside verses the outside.  If this is the case the window should be held in the door with a series of philips head screws. you should be able to unscrew the window and turn it around.  Sometimes the screws are covered with little plastic buttons that match the plastic frame molding that is around the window, just pry them out and you should be able to reverse the window.